# Text automatically goes to the top of a table even if text position immediately after the table

Tags: tables, positioning

```
This is the top


\begin {table}
\caption {Table Title}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| l | l | l |}
\hline
Measurement& Uncertainty & Range  \\ \hline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption*{What is going on}
\end{center}
\end {table}

This is bottom
```

When latex compiles,

```
This is bottom
```

came right after

```
This is the top
```

with the table beneath

```
This is the top
```

Is there a way I can fix this

Edit:

```
% Search for all the places that say "PUT SOMETHING HERE".


\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,textcomp,amssymb,geometry,graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

% Y
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}


\setlength{\headsep}{0.5in}


\begin{document}


\textbf{Introduction}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te noster impetus vix. Bonorum suscipit te vis, ad mutat dissentiet eos, sea probo voluptatum no. Nullam ridens ex usu. An tincidunt posidonium est. Ut sed iriure nominavi expetenda, duo apeirian prodesset at, affert adolescens accommodare mel cu. Purto habemus sed an, qui voluptatibus conclusionemque et.

Ut brute labitur cotidieque sed, duo iudico erroribus suscipiantur ne. Mea illud ridens postea et. In ius quando partiendo aliquando, duo ei graece veritus disputando, sea iusto oportere philosophia at. Quo in ceteros assentior accommodare, sit quod modus et.
\\\\

\section*{1.}

\begin{itemize}

\item[1.1)]

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te noster impetus vix. Bonorum suscipit te vis, ad mutat dissentiet eos, sea probo voluptatum no. Nullam ridens ex usu. An tincidunt posidonium est. Ut sed iriure nominavi expetenda, duo apeirian prodesset at, affert adolescens accommodare mel cu. Purto habemus sed an, qui voluptatibus conclusionemque et.

Ut brute labitur cotidieque sed, duo iudico erroribus suscipiantur ne. Mea illud ridens postea et. In ius quando partiendo aliquando, duo ei graece veritus disputando, sea iusto oportere philosophia at. Quo in ceteros assentior accommodare, sit quod modus et.
d, duo iudico erroribus suscipiantur ne. Mea illud ridens postea et. In ius quando partiendo aliquando, duo ei graece veritus disputando, sea iusto oportere philosophia at. Quo in ceteros assentior accommodare, sit quod modus et.

\begin {table}
\caption {Table Title}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{| l | l | l |}
    \hline
    Measurement& Uncertainty & Range  \\ \hline
    \hline
   \end{tabular}
   \caption*{Caption}
\end{center}
 \end {table}




Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te noster impetus vix. Bonorum suscipit te vis, ad mutat dissentiet eos, sea probo voluptatum no. Nullam ridens ex usu. An tincidunt posidonium est. Ut sed iriure nominavi expetenda, duo apeirian prodesset at, affert adolescens accommodare mel cu. Purto habemus sed an, qui voluptatibus conclusionemque et.

Ut brute labitur cotidieque sed, duo iudico erroribus suscipiantur ne. Mea illud ridens postea et. In ius quando partiendo aliquando, duo ei graece veritus disputando, sea iusto oportere philosophia at. Quo in ceteros assentior accommodare, sit quod modus et.


\end{itemize}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Your table `floats` around, i.e. LaTeX puts it a place where it 'thinks' it would fit best.

Comment: If you would prefer it not to float, try `\begin{table}[ht]`

Comment: Thanks I fixed the problem by adding `[htb]`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes It can still float if you do that.

Comment: @user3685689 See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/ and (for the 'whole story' on float placement) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes, obviously it "can" still float.  But often times, it will fix it.  And that is why I suggested the OP to "try" it.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Fair enough, and I know you know that it can still float, I just thought it could be a little bit misleading when phrased like that, hence my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This propositon does not use a floating table, by omission of the `table` environment. However, in this case, `\captionof[table]{Caption title}` has to be used (package `caption` is required for that)

I did not address other aspects of this MWE by the OP (especially the vertical lines in the table ;-))

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,textcomp,amssymb,geometry,graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

% Y
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}


\setlength{\headsep}{0.5in}


\begin{document}


\textbf{Introduction}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te noster impetus vix. Bonorum suscipit te vis, ad mutat dissentiet eos, sea probo voluptatum no. Nullam ridens ex usu. An tincidunt posidonium est. Ut sed iriure nominavi expetenda, duo apeirian prodesset at, affert adolescens accommodare mel cu. Purto habemus sed an, qui voluptatibus conclusionemque et.

Ut brute labitur cotidieque sed, duo iudico erroribus suscipiantur ne. Mea illud ridens postea et. In ius quando partiendo aliquando, duo ei graece veritus disputando, sea iusto oportere philosophia at. Quo in ceteros assentior accommodare, sit quod modus et.
\\\\

\section*{1.}

\begin{itemize}

\item[1.1)]

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te noster impetus vix. Bonorum suscipit te vis, ad mutat dissentiet eos, sea probo voluptatum no. Nullam ridens ex usu. An tincidunt posidonium est. Ut sed iriure nominavi expetenda, duo apeirian prodesset at, affert adolescens accommodare mel cu. Purto habemus sed an, qui voluptatibus conclusionemque et.

Ut brute labitur cotidieque sed, duo iudico erroribus suscipiantur ne. Mea illud ridens postea et. In ius quando partiendo aliquando, duo ei graece veritus disputando, sea iusto oportere philosophia at. Quo in ceteros assentior accommodare, sit quod modus et.
d, duo iudico erroribus suscipiantur ne. Mea illud ridens postea et. In ius quando partiendo aliquando, duo ei graece veritus disputando, sea iusto oportere philosophia at. Quo in ceteros assentior accommodare, sit quod modus et.




\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{| l | l | l |}
      \multicolumn{3}{c}{Table title} \tabularnewline
      \multicolumn{3}{c}{} \tabularnewline
    \hline
    Measurement& Uncertainty & Range  \\ \hline
    \hline
   \end{tabular}
   \captionof*{table}{Caption}
\end{center}




Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te noster impetus vix. Bonorum suscipit te vis, ad mutat dissentiet eos, sea probo voluptatum no. Nullam ridens ex usu. An tincidunt posidonium est. Ut sed iriure nominavi expetenda, duo apeirian prodesset at, affert adolescens accommodare mel cu. Purto habemus sed an, qui voluptatibus conclusionemque et.

Ut brute labitur cotidieque sed, duo iudico erroribus suscipiantur ne. Mea illud ridens postea et. In ius quando partiendo aliquando, duo ei graece veritus disputando, sea iusto oportere philosophia at. Quo in ceteros assentior accommodare, sit quod modus et.


\end{itemize}



\end{document}
```

[image]